# Dont stop subsequent activites in Automation if step fails

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have an Automation which has a series of activities, one of them being an import of a file into my Subscribers list (after being generated by SQL and a data extract). After the import is completed there is half a dozen other activities that need to completed but only once this the import is done first. I have found some cases where the import will be empty (which is expected, but not very frequent) which will cause the automation to fail and stop processing the steps after the failed activity.

Is there a way I can continue the remaining activities in an automation if a previous step has failed? The failed step must run before all subsequent activities so they cannot be run alongside each other in the same step.

Comment: Have you tried setting it up as 2 different automations? And just set a start time of X minutes difference (expected run time of Automation 1) between Automation 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you contact support I believe they can enable Allow blank file processing,this allows imports to continue when a file is blank.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000e3glQAA